# 6-month Status Update

Tags: discussion

Just thought I'd take a minute to highlight where we are with the Joomla Stack Exchange site after 6 months. (I believe the launch was around the 22nd of April.)

This is actually the first time I've seen not one section say "Needs Work", so good job everyone!

[image: Area51 Stats for Joomla Q&A Site]

For up-to-date stats, check out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla

Comment: The only metric I am afraid we won't make it green, is the Questions/Day... because Joomla usually works and it's hard to have questions to ask (ha!!!)

Comment: @FFrewin - It will eventually start to rise once more people start asking questions on JSE rather than SO :)

Comment: Thinking that it's still hard to make people stop posting in SO... as far as there are so many Q/A there, that appearing when googling something, then their first thought would be to post there. This might change eventually. Wondering if that would be possible to move all Joomla questions from SO to JSE...

Answer (score 4):

Really pleased with this, given how the last JSE proposal went. JSE proving to be a really useful tool for engaging with the Joomla community in addition to the bug tracker / Github.

Is there any way we can pull in more users from the Joomla forums? I've had much greater success getting good answers here than there, and think we'd get a more diverse mix of questions if we started selling JSE over there.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I've been mostly thinking about how to redirect the traffic from StackOverflow here. I'm not sure if we can get an ad or anything similar approved on the forum, but it could be worth asking.

Comment: I think getting subscribed to joomla tags on SO, then commenting on those questions to get them moved over is a good short/medium-term approach. The forums are still very active though, and (I think) the SE approach to QA is much more appropriate for the majority of queries than the forum (except perhaps for 'help I've been hacked' type posts) - certainly the developer forums.

Comment: Definitely agree. And not only do you get a better answer here, but it tends to be much more search engine friendly here, which limits repeat questions to a degree.

Comment: Absolutely. Not sure what the inroads to the forum would be (and if we'd be stepping on toes...), but certainly an avenue to explore. Do you know of any JSE members also working within / around the forum team?

Comment: it's always much harder to find an answer in the forums, where you need to scroll down and read everyone's posts... which are not answers. In contrast in JSE - finding a solution to a problem is much more efficient.

Comment: Do people still use the Joomla forums? lol. @codinghands, I might be able to get a contact from the Joomla forum team. What exactly were you planning on asking them?

Answer (score 3):

That's excellent news. I've been a bit worried about the Questions per day stats, but I'm confident it'll keep growing when Visits per day picks up.

As for the answer ratio, although there are [questions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/change-background-of-entire-website) that only have one possible answer (mostly [fix-my-code](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fix-my-code)), many questions would benefit from additional answer and different solutions. I encourage everyone to look through [old questions with few answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/joomla/query/56690/second-opinion-needed) and see if something can be added or updated.

Comment: Yeah, visits per day has skyrocketed over the last month or two (from less than 500 to over 1,000). I figure that that should pick up the questions per day as well.

Answer (score 3):

Been interesting. I've been checking the Area 51 stats nearly every day (yes, I have no life) and seen a massive sudden increase in the visits per day. It was trailing around 700+- for a while then boomed up to 1100+ which is great.

I've been also looking through the users with a rep of less than 200 to see if they have any questions/answers that deserve upvotes, to try and boost the avid users up.

Hopefully the stats will not go back to "Needs Work" and continue to increase.

**Great job everyone**

## Update:

To boost the user activity just that little bit more, we should start urging people who have posted their question on SO to post them on JSE, seeing as migration requests seem to be rejected left, right and center.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the same thing, several flags on obvious Joomla questions where rejected for no apparent reason. Is it OK to comment and recommend to use JSE, or would we be crossing some invisible line?

Comment: I personally think we should urge as much as possible. JSE is for Joomla questions :)

Comment: I was looking the stats almost everyday as well... but I had to be offline for some days recently. I left visits at about 700 and when I came back I saw what you are describing here, which was a big surprise.

Comment: As for the calls in SO, whenever I am there and seeing a Joomla question, I usually place a comment about JSE.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to add a comment on Joomla related questions on SO explaining that the poster might get a better response on JSE especially where the question has been asked and there has been no response for several days or longer. That's what I've been doing and some questions have been resubmitted to JSE.